# Does Array.ToString() provide a useful output?

Tags: c#

If I have an array and perform a `ToString()` does that just string together the array values in one long comma seperated string or is that not possible on an array?

Comment: Did you try it, and examine the output?

Comment: I don't actually know, but you could try it...

Comment: I have an array of MyCustomType[] not string[]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you have an array of `string`s, then you can use `String.Join`:

```
string[] values = ...;

string concatenated = string.Join(",", values);
```

**Option 2**

If you're dealing with an array of any other type and you're using .NET 3.5 or above, you can use LINQ:

```
string concatenated = string.Join(",",
                          values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: @Sky: string.Split is a BCL class function. The signature is no different for this function in any other .NET language. I'm not saying that there is no language that doesn't "put values first" (though I'm not sure that's really a way of classifying a language), I'm saying that whether you're using it in C#, VB.NET, etc. you'll pass the delimiter first.

Comment: In my case it's a custom object array.  I'll have to implement IEnumerable then

Comment: Adam, so you use string.split on your arrays?

Comment: @coffee: Any array already implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is the type of the array). I'm not sure I understand your question about `string.Split`.

Comment: mine is just an array of a custom object type.  So I can just do string.split on that?

Comment: so I have an array of MyType[] not a string[]

Comment: If you're using .NET 3.5, then you can use option #2. This uses LINQ to create a `string[]` from your original `MyType[]`, then uses `string.Join` on them. `string.Split` won't help you in this scenario.

Comment: In the (unlikely) event that you (or, more likely, someone who's found this question) has an array of `char[]` called `c`, then you'd only need `new string(c);` as well. Which I'm adding here because I felt stupid when Google reminded me just a moment ago  ;o)

Answer (score 18):

You can certainly do that, but it's not the default behaviour. The easiest way to do that (from .NET 3.5 anyway) is probably:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", array.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

[MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) has a built-in method to do this:

```
string joined = array.ToDelimitedString();
```

or specify the delimited explicitly:

```
string joined = array.ToDelimitedString(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `ToString` of an array will give you the Type name "string" of the object. Use the `String.Join` method instead.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't (as you noticed).

For string arrays you can use:

```
string.Join(",", myArray)
```

for other arrays I think you need to code it yourself.

Comment: if the ToString of the arrayed Type is acceptable, which for all value types it is, a simple string join will work.  Most other types that are meant for exposure will also have a default ToString that is friendly.

Comment: String.Join won't call ToString() automatically - you need to convert the string to a string array to start with, as per my answer and Adam's.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this effect you should call String.Join(string, string[])

I.e.

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string.Join(",", stringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Concat(Object[] args)`. This calls the `ToString()` method of every object in `args`. In a custom class you can override the `ToString()` method to achieve custom string conversion like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private int number;

    public YourClass(int num)
    {
        number = num;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "#" + number;
    }
}
```

Now you can concatenate an array of instances of your custom class:

```
YourClass[] yourArray = { new YourClass(1), new YourClass(2), new YourClass(3) };
string concatenated = string.Concat(yourArray);
```

**Unfortunately** this method does not add any delimiters, but I found it to be elegant. The variable `concatenated` will contain `"#1#2#2"`.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does Array.ToString() provide a useful output?*

> No (as already answered), but...

There is an elegant solution in case of **.NET** (or **.NET Core**, or **.NET Standard**): [StringBuilder.AppendJoin(String, Object[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendjoin?view=net-7.0#system-text-stringbuilder-appendjoin(system-string-system-object()))

It's in 2 times better solution than LINQ (option 2 in accepted answer) in terms of consumption of computing resources (2 times faster)

```
string concatenated = new StringBuilder()
                          .AppendJoin(", ", values).ToString();
```