# Cannot Solve "index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: asp.net, arrays, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am working in C# with ASP.NET. I am familiar with this error but this time I can't solve it.
I have text in a drop-down list like this:

> राम कुमार सिंह 8s2w8r

```
here राम कुमार सिंह is the name in HINDI while 8s2w8r is users' ID.
```

I need to separate these two values and need to pass them as session variables. The logic I am using is depicted in the code.

```
 public string reverse(string s)
        {
            char []temp=s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(temp);
            return (temp.ToString());
        }


        string dropdowntextreversed=reverse(DropDownList1.Text);
        char []delim=new char[]{' '};
        string []parts=dropdowntextreversed.Split(delim,2);
        string family_head_uid = reverse(parts[0]);
        string family_head = reverse(parts[1]);
        Session.Add("family_head", family_head);
        Session.Add("family_head_uid", family_head_uid);
        Response.Redirect("/WebForm1.aspx");
```

I always get an error as the index was outside the bounds of the array! I don't understand this because I am breaking the string into 2 parts so it should have parts[0] and parts[1]. Please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following reverse method:

```
public string reverse(string s)
{
    return String.Join(String.Empty, s.ToCharArray().Reverse());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. Can you please  tell me why my method was not working?

Comment: Think of it this way: `int[] a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; string b = a.ToString();` What would you expect `b` to be?

Comment: well, to be honest I would answer "123", but I know that I am wrong but why?

Comment: True, by default in C# `ToString()` will return the type of the instance, unless it is overridden by the class implementation. An `int[]` implements internally `IEnumerable` and it does not override `ToString()`, so it returns the type as the default behavior. The same applies to `char[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are splitting the string into **MAXIMUM** 2 parts, but if there's only one you will get probably one part.

Read this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx)

Try to assert that `parts.Length is == 2` or to access elemnts only there atre two elements

Comment: I checked, **parts.Length** is always equal to 1. Why?

Comment: No what i am saying is that if your string doesnt contain more than one part then you will get only one part, so trying to access parts[1] would get you an OutofBoundsException

Comment: Sir, I will always have **atleast two parts**. I have programmed it such a way that there exits a space in between name and UID.

Comment: At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: At `string family_head = reverse(parts[1]);`

Comment: then check the values in the array on this line so you can know how comes you have only one part.

Comment: I have tried and printed `parts.Length` on the page and it is always 1, whatsoever. Why is it behaving such a way?

Comment: Please check if I have made a logical mistake in my `reverse()` method.

Comment: is the value in dropdowntextreversed ok? doesnt it contain an empty space?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245581/array-tostring). As I think there is a problem in the `temp.ToString()` which will return `System.Char[]` rather than the value which are you looking for. Use [string.join](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join) instead will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is returning `System.Char[]`. But why would I use **String.Join** when I need to reverse a string?

Comment: because you are reversing the array ok. But not creating back the string which you need. So you will have to use string.join method

Comment: do you want to reverse the whole string then you can go by @Candide?