# Get column index based on value in row

Tags: c#

I want to get the column index based on value in first row that contains "TOTAL". I found that it is totally different to get the column index based on row value instead of column.

[image]

I tried this and it shows the column index is 0 but it is supposedly to be 19

```
var badColumns = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Where (c => c.ToString().Contains("TOTAL QTY")).Select((c, i) => i).ToArray();

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", badColumns));
```

Comment: badColumns is an array if you print array to string you will get string as you typed with [] instead of (). try `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(", ", badColumns))` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245581/array-tostring)

Comment: You are selecting index instead of value.

Comment: @Rafal It give me 0, I updated my question. Kindly take a look again.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are filtering columns before indexing them you should do it like this:

```
var badColumns = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray
     .Select((c, i) => new{c,i})
     .Where(x => x.c.ToString().Contains("TOTAL QTY"))
     .Select(x => x.i)
     .ToArray();

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", badColumns));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the ToString() method of the array class, and it will show that.
I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < badColumns.Length; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(badColumns[i].ToString());
}
```

This will show a message box for each of the elements in the badColums array, and it will call the ToString method of your object.

If you only want one MessageBox with all the elements do this:

```
string badColumnsString = "";
for(int i = 0; i < badColumns.Length; i++)
{
    badColumnsString += badColumns[i].ToString() + " ";
}
badColumnsString = badColumnsString.TrimEnd(' ');
MessageBox.Show(badColumnsString);
```

Comment: It doesnt give me the right column index, I updated my question.