# Converting ICollection<object> to array of string items

Tags: c#

When I add a watch to my variable this is how it looks inside:
[image]

What I want to get out of that is a string `array of items` in it so in this case a `{"item1", "item2", "item3"}` but somehow I can't figure out why my code is not working. It gives me an empty list.
What is it I am doing wrong and could I even do it better?
Here is what I tried:

```
            List<string> itemsInReslt = new List<string>();
            foreach (IDictionary<string, object> r in result)
            {
                foreach (object value in r.Values)
                {
                    itemsInReslt.Add(value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: `result.SelectMany(r => r.Values).Select(value => value.ToString()).ToList()` What is the actual type of `result`?

Comment: it is IEnumberable<Dictinary<string,object>>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Array.ToString() provide a useful output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245581/does-array-tostring-provide-a-useful-output)

Comment: But that `object` is an array. You can't `ToString` an array like that. Instead you need to use `string.Join` or something. Consider maybe using a JSON serializer to do all this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK solved it myself.

```
var value = result.Single()["FooArray"] as string[];
var valuesInArray = value.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your object in your dictionary is not string[]. Use this:

```
        var itemsInResult = new List<string>();
        foreach(var resultValue in result)
        {
            foreach (var dictionaryItem in resultValue)
            {
                itemsInResult.Add(dictionaryItem.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Otherwise:

```
        var itemsInResult = new List<string>();
        foreach(var resultValue in result)
        {
            foreach (var dictionaryItem in resultValue)
            {
                itemsInResult.AddRange(dictionaryItem.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile on .Value.  Did you mean .Values? It only gives me .Values.

Comment: Sorry did not know for what you used the first foreach loop but I think now I understand. Check the updated solution. @LonelySemiColon